# 3 Arguments - Calculating BMI - Python

Tags: python, function

So basically Im trying to create a program which should do the following in python:

A program that contains a function called `calculate_bmi` which when it is called, has three arguments - the first argument is an integer variable containing the height in feet, the second argument is an integer variable containing the height in inches, the third argument is the person's weight in pounds. The main program asks the user to enter feet, then inches, then pounds. These variables are then sent to the function. The function calculates and prints the BMI value.

The code below is my attempt but I'm having no luck; I cannot seem to convert the height to feet as well. Any help would really be appreciated.

```
def calculate_bmi():

   height_feet = int(input("Please enter height in feet"))
   height_inches = int(input("Please enter height in inches"))
   weight_pounds = int(input("Please enter weight in pounds"))

   calculate_bmi(height_feet,height_inches,weight_pounds)

   bmi = (weight_pounds / height_inches) * 703

   print (bmi)
```

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve] and a matching, clear problem statement.

Comment: i just want to know if i have used the functions in my code correctly, because when i run the program nothing shows up. The user must enter 3 values as stated above and then the result will be BMI.

Answer (score 0):

You define a function that takes no arguments, and then you're calling it recursively with arguments. Furthermore, you are using the int function on the input value, which, by default, is an integer. Finally you are asking the user to give the height in feet, although you don't really use it.

```
def calculate_bmi():
    height_inches = input('..text..')
    weight_pounds = input('..text..')
    bmi = (float(weight_pounds) / height_inches)*703
    print bmi

calculate_bmi()
```

First define your function, which asks for the 2 necessary values, calculates the result and then prints it. After that simply call your function and you get the desired result. I suggest you study python's documentation about functions to learn how they work.